# How to get a score table to read as numbers instead of characters (android)

Tags: android, sql, char, long-integer

I'm creating an android game with a high score table, currently the scores in the database aren't seen as numbers so they aren't displaying in the right order.

This is how my database is created

```
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_SCORE + " NUM);");
```

and this is my method for returning the score

```
    public String getScore() {

    String[] score = new String[]{ KEY_SCORE };
    Cursor c = scoreDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, score, null, null, null, null, KEY_SCORE+" DESC"); 
    String scoreResult = "";

    int iRow2 = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SCORE); //Cursor looking for column setting equal to these ints.



    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) { 
        //Move to first row - where cursor starts and moves to next row as long it is not after last row.
        scoreResult = scoreResult + c.getString(iRow2) + "\n"; 
        //Returning value of row that it is currently on.
    }
    return scoreResult; //returning result
}
```

i seen someone that used a "Long" variable type to do this.. but couldn't quite get it to work ! if anyone can help or has any resources that may help me that'd be great !

Answer (score 0):

Well, you said:

> currently the scores in the database aren't seen as numbers so they aren't displaying in the right order.

This seems to be a mistake. If scores are really numbers then the database of the game you're developing should store them as numbers. You'll have less headaches if you do that.

If you correct your data, the `order by desc` should work.

**Edit:**

> thats my point, i don't know how to correct it ! – Carla Dessi

Well, you didn't even mention what DBMS you're using. Now based on your `create table` statement that dbms supports the data type `INTEGER`. Why don't you store `KEY_SCORE` as such instead of `NUM`?

Comment: i tried it with integer and it doesn't make a difference.. it sort of orders it, but comes up like 9,8,5,3,2,1,19,15,11,0,-1 and so on..